# Install Latest NPM Version in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I am trying to upgrade npm to the latest version in a Dockerfile, but I cannot run `npm install -g npm@latest`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda

# Core installs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y git vim wget build-essential python3 ca-certificates bzip2 libsm6 npm nodejs && \
    apt-get clean

RUN npm install -g npm@latest
```

The error output I get is:

```
[+] Building 9.7s (7/24)                                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.89kB                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:jessie                                                                                                   0.7s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 292B                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [ 1/20] FROM docker.io/library/debian:jessie@sha256:32ad5050caffb2c7e969dac873bce2c370015c2256ff984b70c1c08b3a2816a0                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/20] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get upgrade &&     apt-get install -y git vim wget build-essential python3 ca-certificates bzip2 libsm6 npm node  0.0s
 => ERROR [ 3/20] RUN npm install -g npm@latest                                                                                                                    8.9s
------                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [ 3/20] RUN npm install -g npm@latest:                                                                                                                               
#6 3.917 npm WARN engine npm@8.14.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})                                       
#6 8.272 npm WARN package.json abbrev@1.1.1 No README data                                                                                                              
#6 8.274 npm WARN package.json agent-base@6.0.2 No README data                                                                                                          
#6 8.274 npm WARN package.json agentkeepalive@4.2.1 No README data                                                                                                      
#6 8.275 npm WARN package.json aproba@2.0.0 No README data
#6 8.275 npm WARN package.json archy@1.0.0 No README data
#6 8.276 npm WARN package.json are-we-there-yet@3.0.0 No README data
#6 8.278 npm WARN package.json asap@2.0.6 No README data
#6 8.279 npm WARN package.json balanced-match@1.0.2 No README data
#6 8.279 npm WARN package.json bin-links@3.0.1 No README data
#6 8.280 npm WARN package.json brace-expansion@2.0.1 No README data
#6 8.280 npm WARN package.json chownr@2.0.0 No README data
#6 8.281 npm WARN package.json cacache@16.1.1 No README data
#6 8.281 npm WARN package.json cidr-regex@3.1.1 No README data
#6 8.281 npm WARN package.json cli-columns@4.0.0 No README data
#6 8.282 npm WARN package.json cli-table3@0.6.2 No README data
#6 8.283 npm WARN package.json clone@1.0.4 No README data
#6 8.284 npm WARN package.json color-name@1.1.4 No README data
#6 8.285 npm WARN package.json common-ancestor-path@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.286 npm WARN package.json console-control-strings@1.1.0 No README data
#6 8.286 npm WARN package.json concat-map@0.0.1 No README data
#6 8.287 npm WARN package.json debug@4.3.4 No README data
#6 8.287 npm WARN package.json debuglog@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.288 npm WARN package.json defaults@1.0.3 No README data
#6 8.289 npm WARN package.json dezalgo@1.0.4 No README data
#6 8.290 npm WARN package.json diff@5.0.0 No README data
#6 8.290 npm WARN package.json emoji-regex@8.0.0 No README data
#6 8.292 npm WARN package.json encoding@0.1.13 No README data
#6 8.294 npm WARN package.json fastest-levenshtein@1.0.12 No README data
#6 8.294 npm WARN package.json err-code@2.0.3 No README data
#6 8.295 npm WARN package.json fs-minipass@2.1.0 No README data
#6 8.295 npm WARN package.json fs.realpath@1.0.0 No README data
#6 8.296 npm WARN package.json function-bind@1.1.1 No README data
#6 8.297 npm WARN package.json gauge@4.0.4 No README data
#6 8.297 npm WARN package.json glob@8.0.3 No README data
#6 8.298 npm WARN package.json graceful-fs@4.2.10 No README data
#6 8.298 npm WARN package.json has@1.0.3 No README data
#6 8.299 npm WARN package.json has-unicode@2.0.1 No README data
#6 8.300 npm WARN package.json hosted-git-info@5.0.0 No README data
#6 8.300 npm WARN package.json http-cache-semantics@4.1.0 No README data
#6 8.301 npm WARN package.json http-proxy-agent@5.0.0 No README data
#6 8.301 npm WARN package.json ignore-walk@5.0.1 No README data
#6 8.302 npm WARN package.json imurmurhash@0.1.4 No README data
#6 8.303 npm WARN package.json infer-owner@1.0.4 No README data
#6 8.303 npm WARN package.json humanize-ms@1.2.1 No README data
#6 8.304 npm WARN package.json inflight@1.0.6 No README data
#6 8.312 npm WARN package.json inherits@2.0.4 No README data
#6 8.312 npm WARN package.json ini@3.0.0 No README data
#6 8.313 npm WARN package.json init-package-json@3.0.2 No README data
#6 8.313 npm WARN package.json iconv-lite@0.6.3 No README data
#6 8.314 npm WARN package.json ip@1.1.8 No description
#6 8.314 npm WARN package.json ip@1.1.8 No README data
#6 8.315 npm WARN package.json is-cidr@4.0.2 No README data
#6 8.315 npm WARN package.json is-core-module@2.9.0 No README data
#6 8.316 npm WARN package.json is-lambda@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.316 npm WARN package.json isexe@2.0.0 No README data
#6 8.317 npm WARN package.json json-parse-even-better-errors@2.3.1 No README data
#6 8.317 npm WARN package.json json-stringify-nice@1.1.4 No README data
#6 8.318 npm WARN package.json jsonparse@1.3.1 No README data
#6 8.318 npm WARN package.json just-diff@5.0.3 No README data
#6 8.319 npm WARN package.json just-diff-apply@5.3.1 No README data
#6 8.321 npm WARN package.json lru-cache@7.12.0 No README data
#6 8.321 npm WARN package.json minimatch@5.1.0 No README data
#6 8.321 npm WARN package.json make-fetch-happen@10.1.8 No README data
#6 8.322 npm WARN package.json minipass-collect@1.0.2 No repository field.
#6 8.322 npm WARN package.json minipass-collect@1.0.2 No README data
#6 8.323 npm WARN package.json minipass@3.3.4 No README data
#6 8.324 npm WARN package.json minipass-flush@1.0.5 No README data
#6 8.324 npm WARN package.json minipass-fetch@2.1.0 No README data
#6 8.325 npm WARN package.json minipass-json-stream@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.325 npm WARN package.json minipass-pipeline@1.2.4 No repository field.
#6 8.325 npm WARN package.json minipass-pipeline@1.2.4 No README data
#6 8.326 npm WARN package.json minizlib@2.1.2 No README data
#6 8.326 npm WARN package.json minipass-sized@1.0.3 No README data
#6 8.327 npm WARN package.json mkdirp-infer-owner@2.0.0 No README data
#6 8.327 npm WARN package.json mute-stream@0.0.8 No README data
#6 8.328 npm WARN package.json negotiator@0.6.3 No README data
#6 8.328 npm WARN package.json normalize-package-data@4.0.0 No README data
#6 8.329 npm WARN package.json npm-audit-report@3.0.0 No README data
#6 8.329 npm WARN package.json npm-bundled@1.1.2 No README data
#6 8.330 npm WARN package.json npm-normalize-package-bin@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.330 npm WARN package.json npm-install-checks@5.0.0 No README data
#6 8.331 npm WARN package.json cmd-shim@5.0.0 No README data
#6 8.331 npm WARN package.json npm-pick-manifest@7.0.1 No README data
#6 8.331 npm WARN package.json npm-registry-fetch@13.2.0 No README data
#6 8.332 npm WARN package.json npm-package-arg@9.1.0 No README data
#6 8.332 npm WARN package.json https-proxy-agent@5.0.1 No README data
#6 8.333 npm WARN package.json npm-profile@6.2.0 No README data
#6 8.333 npm WARN package.json parse-conflict-json@2.0.2 No README data
#6 8.334 npm WARN package.json npm-user-validate@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.334 npm WARN package.json npmlog@6.0.2 No README data
#6 8.335 npm WARN package.json proc-log@2.0.1 No README data
#6 8.335 npm WARN package.json promise-call-limit@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.335 npm WARN package.json promise-all-reject-late@1.0.1 No repository field.
#6 8.336 npm WARN package.json promise-all-reject-late@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.336 npm WARN package.json promise-retry@2.0.1 No README data
#6 8.337 npm WARN package.json promise-inflight@1.0.1 No README data
#6 8.338 npm WARN package.json promzard@0.3.0 No README data
#6 8.339 npm WARN package.json read-cmd-shim@3.0.0 No README data
#6 8.340 npm WARN package.json read-package-json@5.0.1 No README data
#6 8.340 npm WARN package.json read@1.0.7 No README data
#6 8.340 npm WARN package.json readable-stream@3.6.0 No README data
#6 8.341 npm WARN package.json readdir-scoped-modules@1.1.0 No README data
#6 8.341 npm WARN package.json retry@0.12.0 No README data
#6 8.342 npm WARN package.json once@1.4.0 No README data
#6 8.342 npm WARN package.json safe-buffer@5.2.1 No README data
#6 8.343 npm WARN package.json set-blocking@2.0.0 No README data
#6 8.343 npm WARN package.json signal-exit@3.0.7 No README data
#6 8.344 npm WARN package.json socks@2.6.2 No README data
#6 8.344 npm WARN package.json smart-buffer@4.2.0 No README data
#6 8.345 npm WARN package.json socks-proxy-agent@7.0.0 No README data
#6 8.345 npm WARN package.json spdx-correct@3.1.1 No README data
#6 8.346 npm WARN package.json spdx-exceptions@2.3.0 No README data
#6 8.346 npm WARN package.json read-package-json-fast@2.0.3 No README data
#6 8.347 npm WARN package.json ssri@9.0.1 No README data
#6 8.347 npm WARN package.json spdx-license-ids@3.0.11 No README data
#6 8.348 npm WARN package.json string_decoder@1.3.0 No README data
#6 8.348 npm WARN package.json tar@6.1.11 No README data
#6 8.349 npm WARN package.json color-convert@2.0.1 No README data
#6 8.349 npm WARN package.json tiny-relative-date@1.3.0 No README data
#6 8.350 npm WARN package.json treeverse@2.0.0 No README data
#6 8.350 npm WARN package.json unique-filename@1.1.1 No README data
#6 8.351 npm WARN package.json util-deprecate@1.0.2 No README data
#6 8.352 npm WARN package.json unique-slug@2.0.2 No README data
#6 8.352 npm WARN package.json validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4 No README data
#6 8.352 npm WARN package.json validate-npm-package-name@4.0.0 No README data
#6 8.353 npm WARN package.json walk-up-path@1.0.0 No README data
#6 8.354 npm WARN package.json wrappy@1.0.2 No README data
#6 8.354 npm WARN package.json wide-align@1.1.5 No README data
#6 8.355 npm WARN package.json yallist@4.0.0 No README data
#6 8.355 npm WARN package.json write-file-atomic@4.0.1 No README data
#6 8.365 npm WARN package.json spdx-expression-parse@3.0.1 No README data
#6 8.819 npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
#6 8.819 npm ERR!     at errorResponse (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
#6 8.819 npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
#6 8.819 npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
#6 8.820 npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
#6 8.820 npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
#6 8.820 npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
#6 8.821 npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
#6 8.822 
#6 8.822 npm ERR! System Linux 5.10.104-linuxkit
#6 8.823 npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm@latest"
#6 8.823 npm ERR! cwd /
#6 8.823 npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
#6 8.823 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
#6 8.824 npm ERR! code E405
#6 8.841 npm ERR! 
#6 8.842 npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
#6 8.843 npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
#6 8.843 npm ERR! not ok code 0
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install -g npm@latest]: exit code: 1
```

How can I get the latest npm version?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to contain only a [mcve]; it seems like 2/3 of the Dockerfile you included is irrelevant to your Node problem?  `debian:jessie` is pretty old (the oldest [Debian release](https://www.debian.org/releases/) that's supported at all); can you use a newer version like `debian:bullseye` and the `npm` it includes, or even use the [Docker Hub `node` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) rather than building your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a follow-up issue because something earlier went wrong. Try to build with `--no-cache` option and look closely to the output log.

Comment: This fixed it, but I also had to use David's suggestion to use `debian:bullseye`